# Cannot Share Mounted SSD with another user

Tags: permissions, ssd

I have a SSD that I use for backing up Email and a few other items. I ran into this problem, believe it or not, trying to run an ANACRON job. This job backs up Thunderbird Email folders, etc. every 15 days.

I am not the only user on the computer, so sometimes the other user logs in first of the day and if the ANACRON job that I created (and tested successfully under my ID) is scheduled to run, it tries to run it from the other user's ID. However, it fails to run and the log indicates that no such file exists. When I check access to the SSD for that user (using Dolphin), indeed, the user has no permissions to even see the disk (but it is mounted) and I can't list the contents in the CLI using ls.

This user belongs to a Group (house) that has the requisite permission (`rwx`) to use the drive.I verified the permissions with `ls -l` and it shows `drwxrwxr-x` which is what I want and, just to verify, the owning group is the same group this user belongs to.

In case you wanted to see the `/etc/fstab` entry - here it is:

```
# /dev/sdg1
UUID=29351526-c46d-403c-9d02-04a638131c4c  /media/nhl/SSD_BKUP  auto  auto,exec,rw  0  0
```

Here is the `ls -l` output:

```
ls -l /media/nhl/SSD_BKUP  
total 264  
drwxrwxr-x  2 root house  16384 Oct 31  2020 lost+found  
drwxrwxr-x  2 nhl  house   4096 Sep 29 14:26 tb_bkup
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: Can I confirm that you have `/dev/sdg1` in your `fstab` file on one line, then the `UUID` on the next? If so, you needn't have the `/dev/sdg1` at all, as you're using the device-specific ID rather than the device-discovery-order ID 

Comment: Thanks for your question. Yes, confirmed, 2 separate lines however I forgot to put the comment tag (#) in front of the /dev/sdg1 line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,after a while I went back to this issue. Everything I needed to do seemed to be done but the other user could not access the shared SSD drive. I then decided to install "ACL" and did a setfacl so that the other user had the specific permissions I wanted to give the user. This resolved the problem although I am not sure why my original setup wasn't working (without ACL), giving the group all the necessary permissions. In any case, this was fixed by setting ACL permissions directly for that specific user to the directory in question (/media/nhl/"drive_name")